# Unable to Upload Files after Server Migration - Possible Permissions Issue

Tags: php, html

I've been encountering an issue for the last three days while working on a project that involves file and text uploads to my server. Every time a user uploads something, a new folder is created on the server in the format YearMonthDay_HourMinuteSecond.

Previously, on my old server running Ubuntu 22.04 with Apache, the code worked fine. However, after changing servers, I'm facing an issue where I can't upload files, but the content gets uploaded. I suspect the problem might be related to folder and file permissions.

Here are the permissions for the directories and files:

Apache folder permission:

```
drwxr-xr-x root root
```

Permissions for the upload page and upload script:

```
\-rw-r--r-- root root upload.html

\-rw-r--r-- root root upload.php
```

Upload directory permissions:

```
drwxrwxrwx www-data www-data  test_upload/
```

I believe the issue might be related to permissions on the server.

upload.html:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" class="upload-form">
      <div class="file-input">
        <input class="pop" id="file" multiple name="file[]" type="file">
        <input class="tit" name="title" placeholder="Title" type="text">
        <textarea cols="50" name="story" placeholder="Story" rows="4"></textarea>
      </div>
</form>
```

active php.ini lines :

```
cat /etc/php/8.1/apache2/php.ini | grep -E "^[^;#]+"
[PHP]
engine = On
short_open_tag = Off
precision = 14
output_buffering = 4096
zlib.output_compression = Off
implicit_flush = Off
unserialize_callback_func =
serialize_precision = -1
disable_functions =
disable_classes =
zend.enable_gc = On
zend.exception_ignore_args = On
zend.exception_string_param_max_len = 0
expose_php = Off
max_execution_time = 30
max_input_time = 60
memory_limit = 128M
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
display_errors = Off
display_startup_errors = Off
log_errors = On
ignore_repeated_errors = Off
ignore_repeated_source = Off
report_memleaks = On
variables_order = "GPCS"
request_order = "GP"
register_argc_argv = Off
auto_globals_jit = On
post_max_size = 8M
auto_prepend_file =
auto_append_file =
default_mimetype = "text/html"
default_charset = "UTF-8"
doc_root =
user_dir =
enable_dl = Off
file_uploads = On
upload_max_filesize = 2000M
max_file_uploads = 200000
allow_url_fopen = On
allow_url_include = Off
default_socket_timeout = 60
extension=mysqli
[CLI Server]
cli_server.color = On
[Date]
[filter]
[iconv]
[imap]
[intl]
[sqlite3]
[Pcre]
[Pdo]
[Pdo_mysql]
pdo_mysql.default_socket=
[Phar]
[mail function]
SMTP = localhost
smtp_port = 25
mail.add_x_header = Off
[ODBC]
odbc.allow_persistent = On
odbc.check_persistent = On
odbc.max_persistent = -1
odbc.max_links = -1
odbc.defaultlrl = 4096
odbc.defaultbinmode = 1
[MySQLi]
mysqli.max_persistent = -1
mysqli.allow_persistent = On
mysqli.max_links = -1
mysqli.default_port = 3306
mysqli.default_socket =
mysqli.default_host =
mysqli.default_user =
mysqli.default_pw =
mysqli.reconnect = Off
[mysqlnd]
mysqlnd.collect_statistics = On
mysqlnd.collect_memory_statistics = Off
[OCI8]
[PostgreSQL]
pgsql.allow_persistent = On
pgsql.auto_reset_persistent = Off
pgsql.max_persistent = -1
pgsql.max_links = -1
pgsql.ignore_notice = 0
pgsql.log_notice = 0
[bcmath]
bcmath.scale = 0
[browscap]
[Session]
session.save_handler = files
session.use_strict_mode = 0
session.use_cookies = 1
session.use_only_cookies = 1
session.name = PHPSESSID
session.auto_start = 0
session.cookie_lifetime = 0
session.cookie_path = /
session.cookie_domain =
session.cookie_httponly =
session.cookie_samesite =
session.serialize_handler = php
session.gc_probability = 0
session.gc_divisor = 1000
session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
session.referer_check =
session.cache_limiter = nocache
session.cache_expire = 180
session.use_trans_sid = 0
session.sid_length = 26
session.trans_sid_tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,form="
session.sid_bits_per_character = 5
[Assertion]
zend.assertions = -1
[COM]
[mbstring]
[gd]
[exif]
[Tidy]
tidy.clean_output = Off
[soap]
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled=1
soap.wsdl_cache_dir="/tmp"
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl=86400
soap.wsdl_cache_limit = 5
[sysvshm]
[ldap]
ldap.max_links = -1
[dba]
[opcache]
[curl]
[openssl]
[ffi]
```

**any help with the problem pleas !**

Comment: Can you share the logs `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: Have you tried uploading a small file? suppose 100kb?

Comment: I attempted to upload a 1MB file, but it didn't appear on the server. Additionally, I also tried uploading a 0.1MB file without success

Comment: Okay, please share the log `/var/log/apache2/error.log` at the time of POST/Upload

Comment: I haven't encountered any errors during the upload process, leading me to believe that the issue might be related to permissions. I've included the entire content of `/var/log/apache2/error.log`, which seems to be the complete log file.

Comment: Can you share the <form> tag first 2-3 lines from upload.html

Comment: Sure, I'll include the initial 2-3 lines of the <form> tag from the upload.html file and add it to the question

Comment: I think i got it. Please install FILEINFO extension. `sudo apt-get install php-fileinfo`

Comment: i already have it :

sudo apt-get install php-fileinfo
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'php8.1-common' instead of 'php-fileinfo'
php8.1-common is already the newest version (8.1.2-1ubuntu2.14).
php8.1-common set to manually installed.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.

Comment: Last option as of my knowledge add "enctype="multipart/form-data" in the <form> tag
`<form action="upload.php" method="post" class="upload-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
`

Comment: Wow daaamn, it worked! I can't believe I was stuck just because of the form enctype. Thanks a lot! <33333

Comment: Please upvote the comments man :P

Comment: I'm a new user :( 
when I attempt to upvote, I receive this message: 'Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" class="upload-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```